# StopForeground doesn't stop foreground service

Tags: c#, android, service, xamarin.android

In my app, i let the user download files. Since its a long action that the user is aware of, i decided to use a service, and start it as a foreground service.I want the service to fire off, finish the download and terminate itself,it shouldn't run all the time.

Here is the call i'm making to start the service, from my main activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(DownloaderService));
intent.PutExtra("id", ID);
StartService(intent);
```

Here is how i start the service as an foreground service, this is inside DownloaderService class

```
public override void OnCreate()
{
    //Start this service as foreground
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(VideoDownloaderService));

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                       .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
                       .SetContentTitle("Initializing")
                       .SetContentText("Starting The Download...")
                       .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent).Build();

    StartForeground(notificationID, notification);
}
```

Here is how i handle the intent

```
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
{
    var id = intent.GetStringExtra("id");

    Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
        await download(id);
        StopForeground(false);
    });

    return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
}
```

The download method must be async.

My problem here is that the service fires off fine, does the `download(id)` method fine, even if i close the app(This is what i wanted). But continues to work even after the call to `StopForeground(false);`.I don't need it to run afterward, since it will still consume resources, and the system won't kill it easily because it's a foreground service.

I could see that my the service running in Android Device Manager, and that my app is still running in debug in VS2015.

Any idea ? Is there any other way to kill the service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [stopForeground()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopForeground(boolean)) method only stops the *foreground state* of the `Service`. And with `false` as the parameter it doesn't even remove the notification, which you probably want it to do, so you could switch that to `true`.

To make the `Service` stop itself you can call [stopSelf()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf()).

So your code could be something like:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
        await download(id);
        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelf();  
    });
```

(...unless there's some minor detail that I missed without actually running the code. But you get the basic idea anyway.)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, i can still see the process, and vs is still debugging. I did try to override the OnDestroy() method, and i see that the  method is being invoked, but the process doesn't die.Maybe its normal ?

Comment: Well, things may be different in Xamarin/C# world. My mind was in "regular Android Java" when writing that as that's what I'm familiar with.

Comment: Should behave the same , since xamarin.android in essentialy just a port over the java version.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this issue? I'm seeing exactly the same, if I have started a foreground service, calling StopForeground then StopSelf doesn't kill the app / debugger.  If I don't call StartForeground then it does close correctly.